# Changing values of multiple rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table such as this

```
name | apples | actual_apples
-----------------------------
John |  5     |   10
-----------------------------
Dave |  3     |   4
```

Which I find by querying for people who have apples != a count of their actual apples using count().

What I want to do, is to change rows like these and set `apples = actual_apples` for each row that is returned.

How can I achieve something like this? I have tried to update the apples property but obviously it won't let me set an attribute to something returning multiple values

(Just assume each apple is unique with its own identifier, thats how I am able to count them)

```
Person {name,age,apples}
has {name(FK(Person)),id(FK(Apples))}
Apples {id,type}
```

the apples attribute is the number of apples a person has. It may be incorrect, its just set by someone inputting data.

I can get the actual number of apples someone has by counting them (this is the query I use to get the table shown above)

```
select p.name, p.apples, count(h.id) as actual_apples
from Person p, has h
where p.name = h.name
group by p.name, p.apples
having apples != count(h.id)
```

Comment: You should show the original table schemma and your query.

Comment: do you mean to update the table so apples =actual_apples?

Comment: I think showing your current query is going to make it a whole lot clearer on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
update p
set p.apples = x.actual_apples
from Person p
join (
    select p.name, count(a.id) as [actual_apples]
    from Person p
    join has on has.name = p.name
    join Apples a on a.id = has.id
    group by p.name) x on p.name = x.name
where p.apples != x.actual_apples
```

Comment: I mentioned that I tried this but the actual_apples is a value returned for each row, hence I cannot set a single attribute to multiple values

Comment: can you please provide the original table schema instead of your query result?

Comment: Ok, will do (characterfilling)

Comment: That did it! Although I wish you would explain a bit more of what you are doing

Comment: I don't know how it's actually called :) Probably this is an UPDATE statement based on value from JOINed aggregated SUBQUERY